# How to connect a Nexus 10 to transfer files?

Tags: usb, android, tablet, mtp

This is a similar question to [How do I connect a Nexus 7 to transfer files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207569/how-to-connect-nexus-7-with-ubuntu) , But the solution given there doesnt work.

How can I connect Nexus 10 on ubuntu. It gives me an error (actually tries to access the device for 30secs and gives up) when I try to open the "Nexuis 10" Icon in the document viewer (Like how a USB is displayed)

Comment: What steps did you follow? Where did it fail? ***What settings did you change on Tablet?***

Comment: Check out http://askubuntu.com/q/87667/14349 . I had the same problem with the Galaxy Nexus. I have had quite a bit of problems with programs using libmtp. The most reliable solution turned out to be gphotofs for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this will work on the 10, but what I did for my 7 was installed a program called gMTP. It's kind of slow and glitchy, but it works. I don't fully understand exactly why it doesn't just open like a regular flash drive though.

Comment: Because it doesnt have external SD card. Only one memory storage is present - Internal memory. Any harddisk/memory storage can be mounted once easily. And internal memory is always mounted on Nexus 7. Now you are trying to mount it at some other place (on your laptop). That's why its not as straight forward as opening a regular flash drive.

Comment: @mac you meant Nexus 10* .... PS: Your name `mac` is a little ironic here :P

Answer (score 1):

I came across this article discussing the topic, if it helpful at all. It specifically speaks to mounting Android 4.0+ devices in Ubuntu and the issues with MTP.

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/how-to-mount-android-40-ubuntu-go-mtpfs.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you update the firmware to 4.2.1 or whatever is the latest version before trying all the libmtp+fuse solutions out there.

When I first for my Nexus 10, it had 4.1 on it. The libmtp steps didnt work on it at that point. Then I updated the firmware to whatever the latest was (4.2.1 for me, took two reboots) and the steps started working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use Go-mtpfs. It's fast and generally better than the slow PoS libmtp based mtpfs

https://github.com/hanwen/go-mtpfs