# Nexus 7 (2013) slow USB transfer, messy file browsing

Tags: usb, android, nexus-7, mtp

Working with Ubuntu 13.04, connecting my Nexus 7 (2nd gen, 2013) via MTP works fine. I just connect the Nexus 7 and Nautilus immediately opens up in the correct directory. No more need to fiddle around with third-party tools as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207569/how-do-i-connect-a-nexus-7-to-transfer-files).

There are two issues that are really bugging me, though:

1. **Transferring files via USB is really slow**. I am using USB 3.0 but Nautilus says my transfer rate is fixed at about 1MB/s which is way too slow for USB 3.0. This might be a problem of calculating the correct transfer rate but I can tell you that the transfer speed is nowhere near the full potential of USB 3.0
2. **Navigating files on the Nexus 7 is quirky**. This might be an MTP issue but it just feels odd. If I create a new directory on my Nexus 7 via Nautilus, I need to "refresh" the current directory (i.e. move to the parent directory and enter the subdirectory again) so that the newly created directory becomes visible for me.

My USB works fine using other devices such as flash drives and USB HDDs.

I haven't found any advice on these problems yet and I'm not sure whether this affects others as well.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue and after replace the microusb with new fresh one the problem solved altough channging the cable may solve it easier