# after using the terminal,wireless connection is gone

Tags: usb, files, transfer

Yesterday I was looking online to see how can I transfer pictures,files from my Nexus 7 tablet to my desktop computer with the usb cable.. I've found several support forums like this one I'm using right now,someone has already asked a question like mine so I followed the best answer, I typed the commands in the terminal as the helper suggested,then I restarted my desktop pc,after that it didn't connect any more,it connects wireless usually,but since yesterday no connection:( I still have the page/link that shows the answer I've followed (the top one) : [How do I connect a Nexus 7 to transfer files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207569/how-do-i-connect-a-nexus-7-to-transfer-files?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

I'm also copying an pasting the answer I've followed :

''You have to follow a below procedure to share contents between Ubuntu to Nexus 7.

Install the necessary tools using terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install mtp-tools mtpfs
```

Connect your Galaxy Nexus to your computer. On your phone, open up the notification drawer, and click on “USB Connection type”. Make sure that MTP is selected.

Type these commands in terminal:

```
mtp-detect | grep idVendor
mtp-detect | grep idProduct
```

The output of these commands should give you idVendor and idProduct. Note down the values given, as you'll need them later.

Run this command in terminal:

```
gksu gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

A Gedit window should open. Simply Copy and paste below line.

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="VENDORID", ATTR{idProduct}=="PRODUCTID", MODE="0666"
```

Replace `VENDORID` and `PRODUCTID` with the idVendor and idProduct you had noted down earlier in Gedit.

Save and close the file. Then, disconnect your phone and run these commands:

```
sudo service udev restart
sudo mkdir /media/GalaxyNexus
sudo chmod a+rwx /media/GalaxyNexus
sudo adduser YOURUSERNAME fuse
```

Replace YOURUSERNAME with your Ubuntu user name. Now, run this command:

```
gksu gedit /etc/fuse.conf
```

In the Gedit window, remove the # at the beginning of the last line.

You’re almost done! Now, restart your computer, and then run these three commands:

```
echo "alias android-connect=\"mtpfs -o allow_other /media/GalaxyNexus\"" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "alias android-disconnect=\"fusermount -u /media/GalaxyNexus\"" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Again, do re-type the quotes in each command after you’ve copied, otherwise the command won’t work.

Connect your phone again, and then make sure your phone is using MTP, then run this command:

```
android-connect
```

You will able to connect the Nexus 7 your to your Ubuntu computer.''

after I did this and restarted my pc,I couldn't connect any more with wireless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's strange. You did nothing that can alter you Wireless connexion...

**Option 1. Undo the `source` command :**

Move the .bashrc and reboot

- `sudo chmod 777 ~/.bashrc`
- `sudo mv ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.bkp`
- `sudo reboot`

When restarted, restore your .bashrc

- `sudo mv ~/.bashrc.bkp ~/.bashrc`
- `sudo chmod +x ~/.bashrc`

Restart and see if you have wireless connexion (don't count on it... but who knows?)

**Option 2. Undo your manipulation :**

- `gksu gedit /etc/fuse.conf` : Add a # at the beginning of the last line
- `sudo mv /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules.bkp`
- `sudo service udev restart`
- `sudo apt-get remove --purge mtp-tools mtpfs`
- `sudo reboot`

If still nothing... I really don't know what you did ^^

---

In the future, regarding your android tablet, if you have *13.04 or superior*, it works out-of-the-box (tablet settings to MTP, disable USB debogging if activated)

If you have *12.10 or older*, check : 
http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/upgrade-to-gvfs-with-mtp-support-in.html
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/how-to-mount-android-40-ubuntu-go-mtpfs.html

Note that Google uses a different protocol than other manufacturers. It uses `go-mtpfs` instead of `mtpfs` ('go' for 'google')

Comment: which # should I add at the beginning of the last line?

Comment: also I didn't follow all the steps on the link I attached..I stopped somewhere in the middle because I saw the connection was gone,then using my other computer and trying to fix this problem I searched for other commands and applied that on my disconnected desktop pc..

Comment: I've tried with bios,and many other commands still nothing..for the state it says ''connecting'' but still nothing all day

Comment: can you post the return of `ip link` and `iw dev` ? And with the return of iw dev (likely *wlp1s0* or similar), post the return of `ip link show wlp1s0`

Comment: If you did not follow the guide through, it's possible that the `#` we were talking about is still here and do not have to be added. Your last line of */etc/fuse.conf* must begin with a `#`, that's the most important.

Comment: I don't know what are the ip link and iw dev,I'm really ignorant in this field,but I don't need it anymore since I got the connection fixed  after 25hours just now! thank you very much!!!

Comment: These were commandlines to enter in a terminal. Well, if your problem is solved, and if I helped, don't hesitate to +1 my posts, so I'll gain reputation on Askubuntu community^^

Comment: I didn't follow all the steps and worse I typed all wrong things,for example when it said :sudo service udev restart
sudo mkdir /media/GalaxyNexus
sudo chmod a+rwx /media/GalaxyNexus
sudo adduser YOURUSERNAME fuse

Comment: I should have put my username instead I really put the word ''USERNAME''

Comment: Well, we all have to start somewhere. In the future, don't use commandline starting with SUDO, GKSU or GKSUDO (anytime you are asked for password except booting your computer^^) without knowing what you do or be ok to reinstall your Ubuntu ;) It's a superuser command and can do serious damage.

Comment: I didn't know I should have replaced the word USERNAME with my actual one,I just typed USERNAME:) I'm telling this in case someone does the same mistake..

Comment: It was said in the tutorial to replace USERNAME with your user name x)

Comment: I did a lot of that commands randomly:( women+technology are very dangerous together I guess,how can I check now if I gave any damage to my pc? should I check?

Comment: I know I didn't read it in the first place :(

Comment: now how can I give you a reputation?

Comment: simply press the up arrow in the left of my post ;)

Comment: You can also press the "V" under de up-and-down arrows to accept my post as the answer to your question (do that only if what I said helped you with your question.)

Comment: after I followed what you've said it didn't happen suddenly but after a few minutes it worked I guess it is because of your help

Comment: it doesn't allow me to give you a reputation/vote because I'm new:(