# Moto G2 is not detecting in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-drivers

I am using ubuntu 14.04 . My Motorola Moto G is not detecting when i plug it using usb. Is it because of missing driver? How can i get drver for ubuntu?

Comment: try http://askubuntu.com/questions/207569/how-do-i-connect-a-nexus-7-to-transfer-files